# select first distinct values from two fields

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

This seems incredibly simple, but I'm just not quite putting it together. Say I have the values

```
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 10
 1 | 20
 2 | 10
 2 | 20
```

How could I select from this table such that I get these values in a table:

```
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 10
 2 | 20
```

The same would apply for:

```
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 10
 1 | 20
 1 | 30
 2 | 10
 2 | 20
 2 | 30
 3 | 10
 3 | 20
 3 | 30
```

to get

```
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 10
 2 | 20
 3 | 30
```

I've tried different combinations of distinct on and order by, but these won't work as it really does need to be distinct on both a and b. Maybe a window function...? Using postgres if it matters.

Comment: @klin b is the first unique value from the column b. So if 1 | 10 already exists 2 | 10 would not be valid, must be 2 | 20

Comment: use `ctrl-K` or add 4 spaces at begin of line to format as `code`

Comment: is it guaranteed that each `a` occurs exactly n times?

Comment: In my data set, I believe so. The real complication to my data set is that this operation should only occur on duplicates. so if the set is {1,10}, {1,20}, {2, 10}, {2,20}, {3,999} result should be {1,10}, {2,20}, {3,999}. Basically un-cartesian-product duplicates. Maybe that's outside the scope of what I asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `distinct` is the right term here, but if I understand correctly you have a set of values for a and b, and rows for each combination and you want to match the first a with the first b, the second a with the second b, etc. One way to do this is to use window functions to `rank` both columns, and then query only the rows with equals ranks:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM   (SELECT a, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a) AS rank_a,
               b, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY b) AS rank_b
        FROM   myable) t
WHERE  rank_a = rank_b
```

Comment: this will not reliably work if there are unequal number of values in groups.

Comment: Yeah, I was having trouble finding the correct terminology for this, thus not being able to google-fu or even accurately describe the question. Just for fun, what would you call this kind of operation? Reverse cartesian product? @vkp how would anything handle unequal number of values?

Comment: I'm going to go with, yep this is what I asked. The appendent (appendum? meh) to the question involving only performing this operation in the case of duplicates can be solved pretty easily by using your starting point as a subquery and joining to a 'where not in', to be overly vague. Thanks!

Comment: @low_ghost frankly, I wouldn't know what to call this pattern, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

this is an answer to the addendum question, which didn't really seem to be classifiable as a comment. Uses @Mureinik's answer as a basis. I'm sure there's a cleaner sql approach, but for a fast first attempt:

```
WITH duplicate_a 
     AS (SELECT a 
         FROM   temp_table_1 
         GROUP  BY a 
         HAVING Count(1) > 1), 
     unduplicated 
     AS (SELECT a, 
                b 
         FROM   (SELECT a, 
                        Rank() OVER ( ORDER BY a) AS rank_a, 
                        b, 
                        Rank() OVER ( ORDER BY b) AS rank_b 
                 FROM   temp_table_1) t 
         WHERE  rank_a = rank_b 
           AND a IN (SELECT * 
                     FROM   duplicate_a)) SELECT * 
FROM   unduplicated 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   temp_table_1 
WHERE  a NOT IN (SELECT * 
                 FROM   duplicate_a);
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm all for style standardization and linting etc, but this looks like an avant-garde poem. :)

Comment: btw, i didnt understand the addendum. This looks very inneficient, but hey if that work for you, go for it